# Nature of morphism between Brill Noether varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be a smooth curve over complex numbers. Consider the Brill Noether varieties. If $g$ is the genus of $C$. If $r,d$ are positive integers,

$$W^r_d=\{A\in Pic^d(C): h^0(A)\geq r+1\},$$
$$G^r_d=\{(A,V): A\in Pic^d(C), V\in G(r+1,H^0(C,A))\}.$$

We have the projection morphism $p:G^r_d\rightarrow W^r_d$, which is constructed by 'canonical blow up', which doesnt turn out to be blow up in usual sense.

Related question [On the construction of the varieties parametrizing special linear series on a curve](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/121540/on-the-construction-of-the-varieties-parametrizing-special-linear-series-on-a-cu)

Suppose that $W^r_d$ is irreducible, is it true that $G^r_d$ is irreducible as well? If $p$ is the blow up map in the usual sense, this is true. But in this case is this true?

For example if $d\geq r+ g$, then $W^r_d=Pic^d C$ by Riemann Roch. Then is $G^r_d$ irreducible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No in general. For instance, take for $C$ a hyperelliptic cuve of even genus $g=2k$ with $k\geq 6$. Then  $G^2_{g+2}$ has a unique component (of dimension $g+2$) which dominates $\mathrm{Pic}^{g+2}(C)$, but   $p^{-1}((k+1)g^1_2)\cong \mathbb{G}(3,k+2)$ has dimension $3k-3>g+2$, so it cannot be contained in that component.

Comment: how do you say it has a unique component dominating $Pic^{g+2} C$. Is this uniqueness true for any $G^r_d$ with $d=g+r$?

Comment: Yes. There is a nonempty open subset $U\subset\mathrm{Pic}^{g+r}(C)$ such that $h^0(L)=r+1$ for $L\in U$; the map  $p:G^r_{g+r}\rightarrow\mathrm{Pic}^{g+r}(C)$ induces an isomorphism of $p^{-1}(U)$ onto $U$. The closure of $U$ in $G^r_{g+r}$ is the only component dominating $\mathrm{Pic}^{g+r}$.

Comment: I was thinking about your example. The fiber is not in the dominating component. The fiber doesn't contain any complete linear series. Is it possible that a component of $G^r_d$ does not contain any complete linear series?